# Imploding an array of arrays in php

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
$names = [
    ['Joe','Moe','Joey'],
    ['John','Doe','Curly'],
    ['Jimmy','Fallon','Funny']
];
```

What I am trying to do, is implode into a string that looks like this:

```
"('Joe','Moe','Joey'),('John','Doe','Curly'),('Jimmy','Fallon','Funny')"
```

The implode function does not work on an array of arrays, so I did the following, and it accomplishes what I need:

```
$strings = [];
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $strings[] = '('.implode(',',$name).')';
}
$output = implode(',',$strings);
```

My question is: is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Maybe JSON_ENCODE() It will certainly get you a more useful and usable result

Comment: Do you want single-quotes around the names or not? Your example says "yes" but your code says "no"

Comment: Also if this is destined to be crammed into SQL query there are far better ways to do this.

Comment: @Sammitch Yes, it is. What would be a better way to do it for SQL?

Comment: @Phil Yes, I need the single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend on using the array in SQL queries, you're on the wrong track. Instead...

1. Prepare a statement
2. Iterate the array and bind variables
3. Execute the statement

For example

```php
// PDO version
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
foreach ($names as $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
}

// MySQLi version because for some reason people keep using it
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $a, $b, $c);
foreach ($names as [ $a, $b, $c ]) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

---

*Original answer below*

A combination of `implode()` and `array_map()` should work

```php
$output = implode(",", array_map(function($row) {
    return sprintf("(%s)", implode(",", array_map(function($name) {
        return "'$name'";
    }, $row)));
}, $names));
```

This includes the single-quotes around each name and wraps each group in parentheses.

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/PLu1g

Comment: @Rain mine includes quotes around the names

Comment: My solution does add quotes around the names. It produces the exact string I posted in my question.

Comment: @EastsideDev err, [no it doesn't](https://3v4l.org/5nqEB)

Comment: Yes you're right. I forgot to add the quotes

Comment: @EastsideDev I've updated my answer with a better option for SQL statements

Answer (score 1):

When you are modifying data in a foreach loop that is a code smell. Usually you can use a reducer, map or something like that instead. That makes your code easier to understand.

```
$result = array_map( function($item) {
  return "('" . implode( "','", $item) . "')";
}, $names );
$result = '"'.implode( ',', $result ).'"';
```

If you use this code repeatably put it in a function or method that returns the string.